# How to Overcome this reference problem of this array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, dynamic-arrays

even though both share the same memory location
why this result is returning the same array [1,2,3,4,5] why not an empty array [];

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = num;
num = [];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `[]` is a new array.

Comment: Because you arent changing the Array-Content that the reference points to. You are creating a new Array-Instance and that reference is stored inside `num`, leaving the Array of `results` untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't modify but instead completely reassign a `new Array()` (=`[]`) to `num`. `result` *would* change too if you'd only mutate `num` e. g. with `.push()`.

```js
const num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const result = num;
num.push(6);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you just change the `num` reference value, not the array itself, as the `result` variable still points to the array, So the array is still in the memory.

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = num;
num = [];
console.log(result);
```

But if you re-assign `num` value before assignation with `result`, The array will be deleted from memory by garbage collection as it has no referance

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
num = [];
let result = num;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As explaied by @Behemoth, when you reassign a `new Array` to num using `=` operator, `result` still point to the original `array` and `num` point to a new empty `array`.

If you use `splice` instead of reassigning empty array to `num` you can see that `result` is also modified, that is because `splice` modifed to array where`num` and `result` are both pointing in memory :

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = num;

num.splice(0, num.length);

console.log(num);
console.log(result);
```